# Repartitioning issues

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk, disk-management

Good evening,

I am a total noob when it comes to linux/ubuntu and I'm a total disaster at it lol

I am trying to repartition my disk using a bootable usb drive.

My disk allocation looks like this (from GParted)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KcjF.png)

I am trying to reallocate the free space next to dev/sda6 (to then allocate it really to dev/sda7, where I have my actual linux OS)

However when I try to repartition dev/sda6 I get this error: (source Gparted details)

GParted 1.0.0

configuration --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

libparted 3.3

========================================
Device: /dev/sda
Model:  ATA ST500LT012-1DG14
Serial: S3PM5J76
Sector size:    512
Total sectors:  976773168

Heads:  255
Sectors/track:  2
Cylinders:  1915241

Partition table:    msdos

Partition   Type    Start   End Flags   Partition Name  File System Label   Mount Point
/dev/sda1   Extended    4094    948453375   boot        extended
/dev/sda5   Logical 4096    8392703         linux-swap
/dev/sda6   Logical 183248896   848977919           ntfs    DATI
/dev/sda7   Logical 848979968   948453375           ext4

========================================
Device: /dev/sdb
Model:  Sony Storage Media
Serial: none
Sector size:    512
Total sectors:  15204352

Heads:  255
Sectors/track:  2
Cylinders:  29812

Partition table:    none

Partition   Type    Start   End Flags   Partition Name  File System Label   Mount Point
/dev/sdb    Unpartitioned   0   15204351            iso9660 Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS amd64

========================================
Move /dev/sda6 to the left and shrink it from 317.44 GiB to 292.60 GiB  00:00:02    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda6  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda6 (partition)
start: 183248896
end: 848977919
size: 665729024 (317.44 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sda6 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:01    ( ERROR )

ntfsresize -i -f -v '/dev/sda6'  00:00:01    ( ERROR )

ntfsresize v2017.3.23AR.3 (libntfs-3g)
Device name : /dev/sda6
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 340853256704 bytes (340854 MB)
Current device size: 340853260288 bytes (340854 MB)
Checking for bad sectors ...
Checking filesystem consistency ...
100.00 percent completed
Accounting clusters ...
Cluster accounting failed at 31694538 (0x1e39eca): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 31694539 (0x1e39ecb): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 31694540 (0x1e39ecc): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 31694541 (0x1e39ecd): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 31694542 (0x1e39ece): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Filesystem check failed! Totally 5 cluster accounting mismatches.
ERROR: NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!
The usage of the /f parameter is very IMPORTANT! No modification was
and will be made to NTFS by this software until it gets repaired.

Can a kind soul help me interpret this and possibly guide me on how to fix this issue. It is really important to me to reallocate this free space, otherwise I soon won't be able to use my main partition (where my actual linux OS is)

Thank you very much for any help.

Have a wonderful day :)

Comment: Best to only use Windows tools on NTFS. It usually needs chkdsk after any change & chkdsk can only be run from Windows. If you do not have Windows better to just back up data & convert drive gpt (which erases it) and create all new partitions of the size you want. You are moving a lot of data around and each move has risk. You must have backup before any major move like you are doing, anyway. Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the heads up :)